# Ubuntu 13.04 and Compose Key

Tags: 13.04, keyboard-layout

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 and my <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key is broken on my laptop and I can't find the setting to change this to the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> button.

On my old Ubuntu 12.10 had keyboard Layouts setting there I had change it before

Answer (score 0):

The panel you are after is missing.
This solution is just another way to set the compose key. Install dconf-editor, navigate to

```
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources
```

and set xkb-options to `['compose:ralt']`
If xkb-options is missing you'll have to create it.
If it's already there with other options, you'll have to add a comma and append 'compose:lalt' to that array.